# playframework catching PersistenceException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

In the test I try to catch the exception:

Here I'm expecting that software comes without a title - so I'm expecting the PersistenceException would be thrown while saving this entity.

```
@Test
public void saveWithoutTitle() {

    Software software = ...

    try {
        software.save();
        fail("software.title should not be null");
    } catch (PersistenceException ex) {}
}
```

My test fails (i.e. the exception is never happening)

My Software entity class with **@Column(nullable = false !**):

```
@Entity
public class Software extends Model {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String title;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

--

I've already found this the solution how to fix it:

```
  import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

  @Entity
  public class Software extends Model {

    @NotNull
    String title;
```

But again, what's the point to have:

> @Column(nullable = false)

if it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out:

I had a mistake, while building the Software instance. So, it works and throws the exception. I should have used the builder instance - one builder to one test. Then everything works like expected.

```
@Test
public void saveWithoutTitle() {

    SoftwareTemplateBuilder builder = new SoftwareTemplateBuilder();
    Software software = builder.template1().withTitle(null).create();

    try {
        software.save();
        fail("software.title should not be null");
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`javax.persistence.Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#nullable%28%29) is used to specify the details of the database column. The nullable attribute is generally only used when generating the table definitions, and not used at runtime for validation.

[`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) is used at runtime to validate the data before persisting it.

That is why you are receiving PersistenceException when using `@NotNull`. And no exception when you use `@Column(nullable = false)`

Comment: Then, if I use (nullable = false), then, it seems, I still can add null-values into the column. that's something that I'm not expecting.

Comment: @Column(nullable = false) is the JPA way of declaring a column to be not-null. No exception will be thrown by the application itself while persisting, but if the database's table definitions were generated from these annotations, then some JPA exception will be thrown.